# Eclipse/Java not stopping on exception, not showing stacktrace

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, printstacktrace

For some reason, Eclipse for Java stopped showing the stacktrace on exceptions nor is Eclipse stopping on exceptions while in debug. I installed (not upgrade) the latest Eclipse 2023-03 (4.27.0) and referenced the workspace and projects in the hopes that would solve the issue, but Eclipse is still blissfully moving past exceptions.

I have a breakpoint set for Throwable (caught and uncaught), and I also have the debug option set to  suspend execution on uncaught exceptions. Regardless, the exception is caught with my catch statement without suspending execution, and the printStackTrace command does nothing that I can see. There is no output to the console. The showMessageDialog statement does work and displays my failure during initialization message.

If I comment out the try/catch so that the exception is uncaught, then the program appears to terminate immediately without any messages from either me or the system.

Any thoughts on what is happening here?

Below is my tray/catch, and the exception is somewhere in the initializeEX() statement:

```
    try {
        initializeEX();   // the error is somewhere in here...
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        msg = "Failure during console initialization.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, msg, "Cannot load AssetAllocation", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Have you tried adding the exception.toString() in the error dialog? You also should post the initializeEX() code.

Comment: Print the exception, message and stacktrace to the pane and copy the text to your question.

Comment: If you want the debugger to stop, you need to set a breakpoint on the line you want execution to pause at. While uncaught exceptions will crash the JVM, caught exceptions by definition do not, because you caught them and dealt with them.

Comment: You are catching all Exceptions. Is anything throwing Throwable by name? Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your `catch` block?

Comment: daniu, aled, Mike & nitind - thanks for the input. I can't post the code because initializeEX() is a top-level method with many subroutines and thousands of lines of code. Nor can I give you any details on the exception because I haven't found it yet. The catch block around initializeEX is a catch-all fail-safe in the event I didn't gracefully catch something farther down.

Comment: @daniu, thanks for the suggestion and toString does give me the error description. I still need to solve this problem. e.printStackTrace used to work and now it doesn't. I don't know what changed but I need the debuging functionality to show the full stackTrace and to pause execution on exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you managed to get the exception description in the dialog, you can also get the stash trace there.

Create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then a `PrintWriter` from it. Then give that to the `printException()` method.

```
try {
  initializeEX();
} catch (Exception x) {
  try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      PrintStream errorOut = new PrintStream(byteArrayOutputStream)) {
    x.printStackTrace(errorOut);
    msg = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    // joptionpane
 }
}
```

As for why the stask trace isn't printed as is, I assume the standard error stream is changed along the execution (`System.setError(someStream)`).

Comment: Any thoughts on why the breakpoints aren't working?